# How to enable the ad-hoc mode in Android phones without rooting it?

Tags: android, wifi, root, adhoc, mesh-network

I am developing an Android application, which will be used in disaster situations and guide the effected ones, from where to evacuate safely.

A mesh network will be established in a particular area by enabling the ad-hoc mode. It's not possible without rooting a smartphone, that is what I have researched so far.

The source code of Wi-Fi chipset drivers has to be updated to enable the ad-hoc mode in an android phone. Is there any solution, where we can enable the ad-hoc mode without rooting our phone?

Answer (score 2):

Install cyanogenmod 11 or 12, or cyanogen OS 11 or 12. They allow the creation of ad hoc (IBSS) networks from within the wifi settings page. You do need to unlock the phone to install cyanogenmod, but you do not need root access for this or using the ad hoc network features. You could also get a phone, like One Plus One, that runs Cyanogen.